# How can I have a separate cmd+tab for each monitor?

Tags: display

I have a multi-monitor setup with my Mac. I'm looking for the `cmd+tab` menu to only show applications with windows open in the current monitor.

Say I had a running Terminal window open on `Monitor 1` that I wanted to watch over. Say I also had a window of Notes in the background of `Monitor 1`. Then on `Monitor 2` I open a different window of Notes. On `Monitor 2` I want to be able to switch between Notes and another app without affecting what is on `Monitor 1`.

How can I do this?